# Malihu Custom Scrollbar Ajax Content .mCSB_container width not updating

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

The problem is upon load of website, width of .mCSB_container class is ok, but when i click on a link, for example "projects" link, which fires an ajax function, width of .mCSB_container does not change even if contents are not that much. Web page will not load upon click on the link. I tried using the "update" function, but seems like it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

ok I use this plugin and i had te same problem but check this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
            enable:true
        },
        advanced:{
            updateOnContentResize: true    // <- the solution 
        }
    }); 

    // get ajax  link
    $('.Link').click(function(){
        $.get(this.href, function(data) {
            $("#content .mCSB_container").html(data);  // fill .mCSB_container  
            $("#content").mCustomScrollbar("update");   
            $("#content").mCustomScrollbar(
                "scrollTo"
                ,"top"
                ,{scrollInertia:200}
            ); // go to Top content
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```